# Trying to get App Store Connect API key, but 'Keys' tab immediately redirects to previous web page

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

Been hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out if this is a bug on Apple's developer web site or am I missing something?

I am admin and account holder of an individual developer account. Every time I click the 'Keys' tab it just redirects me back to the icon page.

This has halted my iOS app development. I have had a look online and many other people before have had similar issues but could not find a solution. Contacted Apple support as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same in a private window or in another browser?

Comment: Hi Vadim, appreciate you taking the time to reply. I tried safari for ipad and macOS, as well as Chrome and Edge on my PC. Same redirect happens in all of them. Private window redirects as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got the same exact issue. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Are you on VPN and in Safari?  That helped with this issue for us - not being on VPN specifically.

Comment: Currently happening to me too. At first clearing my browser's cache/cookie data fixed the issue. But one day later it's back. Tried clearing cache/cookies and it didn't work. I'm on Safari, tries on private windows, different devices, double checked role (I'm admin) and tried on other browsers. Nothing is working. It's like Apple wants to restrict everyone from that tab...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know when the change happened, this issue was 11 months old when I was writting this.

For me, in February 2024 the page with key administration has been suddenly renamed/moved to **Integrations**. I swear it was "Keys" just the day before.

[image: AppStore integrations]

Comment: Despite being an Admin, I am still not seeing the App Store Connect API tab. All I can see is the `Shared Secret` under `Keys`. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Fantastic! Being struggling with this issue searching every known forum and Apple docs but none of the provided solutions matched what I see on the interface (Mar 31, 2024)