App Store Connect Keys suddenly disappeared
According to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77967129/6727914,

I should see 3 tabs: App Store Connect, In App Purchases and Shared Secrets.
I swear yesterday, it was showing those three tabs correctly. But today, when I checked,  I see nothing.

I cleared browser cookies, changed to Safari, nothing works.  I am stuck

Same for me. It can be a bug or even they changed their UI/functions. Either way, there's nothing we can do.

It's the 1000th problems I faced on this atrocious platform

Probably they moved two of three to anywhere else in the App Store Connect.

Not to mention that all their documentations still points to "Keys" tab , not this "Integrations"

IDK where the others, but shared secret now moves to App -> General -> App Information.

Is there a update on this?

The whole site freezes and shows bugs (I mean today more than usually...)

The page navigation is currently broken, but the pages can still be accessed by navigating directly to:

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/integrations/api (for App Store Connect API)
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/integrations/api/subs (for In-App Purchase)
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/integrations/shared-secret (for Shared Secret)


It is working great (even if needs many page refreshes), thanks!
